# Building a Power BI Connector for Xero API

Tags: oauth-2.0, powerbi, m, xero-api

I am aiming to get data from the Xero API into Power BI for my Organisation. To this end I believe I need to create a custom connector as PBI doesn't have a certified connector for Xero. I have experience in Power BI and M language but this is my first attempt at building a custom connector for Power BI.

As the Xero API requires OAuth2 authentication I used the below resource to create a custom connector in Visual Studio using the Power Query SDK template. I believe I have set up authentication successfully as the connector allows me to log into my Xero account and 'allow access' to the requested resources. It appears that the connection is successful because in Xero my app name appears in Settings>Connected Apps.

https://github.com/jussiroine/OuraCloudConnector/blob/master/OuraCloudConnector/OuraCloudConnector.pq

Once I'm logged in, I receive an error; Details: "Access to the resource is forbidden."

Possible causes I can think of:

- I'm using The Code Flow not PKCE Flow (I assumed this was correct as I'm connecting from Power BI Desktop)
- A problem with my code
- The API url I'm sending is somehow incomplete or incorrect (I'm currently trying: https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/AgedReceivablesByContact?fromDate=2020-01-01&toDate=2021-01-01 )

I have the required permissions in Xero to access the data I'm requesting. I have also included the relevant scopes. Can anyone please advise if they've had success building a custom connector for Power BI or offer some advice on how to resolve this error?

Thank you!

```
    // This file contains your Data Connector logic
section JaimesXeroConnector;

//JaimesXeroConnector OAuth2 values;

client_id = Text.FromBinary(Extension.Contents("client_id.txt"));
client_secret = Text.FromBinary(Extension.Contents("client_secret.txt"));
redirect_uri = "https://oauth.powerbi.com/views/oauthredirect.html";
token_uri = "https://identity.xero.com/connect/token";
authorize_uri = "https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize";
logout_uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/logout.srf";
scopes = {"offline_access openid profile email accounting.transactions accounting.reports.read accounting.transactions.read accounting.reports.read accounting.journals.read accounting.settings accounting.settings.read accounting.contacts accounting.contacts.read accounting.attachments accounting.attachments.read assets projects"
};
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol= "SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12";

// Login modal window dimensions
windowWidth = 720;
windowHeight = 1024;

[DataSource.Kind="JaimesXeroConnector", Publish="JaimesXeroConnector.Publish"]
shared JaimesXeroConnector.Contents = (url as text) =>
    let
        source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url))
    in
        source;


// Data Source Kind description
JaimesXeroConnector= [
    TestConnection = (dataSourcePath) => { "JaimesXeroConnector.Contents", dataSourcePath },
    Authentication = [
        OAuth = [
            StartLogin=StartLogin,
            FinishLogin=FinishLogin,
            Refresh=Refresh,
            Logout=Logout
        ]
    ],
    Label = Extension.LoadString("DataSourceLabel")
];

// Data Source UI publishing description
JaimesXeroConnector.Publish = [
    Beta = true,
    Category = "Other",
    ButtonText = { Extension.LoadString("ButtonTitle"), Extension.LoadString("ButtonHelp") },
    LearnMoreUrl = "https://powerbi.microsoft.com/",
    SourceImage = JaimesXeroConnector.Icons,
    SourceTypeImage = JaimesXeroConnector.Icons
];

// Helper functions for OAuth2: StartLogin, FinishLogin, Refresh, Logout
StartLogin = (resourceUrl, state, display) =>
    let
        authorizeUrl = authorize_uri & "?" & Uri.BuildQueryString([
            response_type = "code",
            client_id = client_id,  
            redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
            state = state,
            scope = scopes
        ])
    in
        [
            LoginUri = authorizeUrl,
            CallbackUri = redirect_uri,
            WindowHeight = 720,
            WindowWidth = 1024,
            Context = null
        ];

FinishLogin = (context, callbackUri, state) =>
    let
        // parse the full callbackUri, and extract the Query string
        parts = Uri.Parts(callbackUri)[Query],
        // if the query string contains an "error" field, raise an error
        // otherwise call TokenMethod to exchange our code for an access_token
        result = if (Record.HasFields(parts, {"error", "error_description"})) then 
                    error Error.Record(parts[error], parts[error_description], parts)
                 else
                    TokenMethod("authorization_code", "code", parts[code])
    in
        result;

Refresh = (resourceUrl, refresh_token) => TokenMethod("refresh_token", "refresh_token", refresh_token);

Logout = (token) => logout_uri;

// see "Exchange code for access token: POST /oauth/token" for details
TokenMethod = (grantType, tokenField, code) =>
    let
        queryString = [
            grant_type = "authorization_code",
            redirect_uri = redirect_uri,
            client_id = client_id,
            client_secret = client_secret
        ],
        queryWithCode = Record.AddField(queryString, tokenField, code),

        tokenResponse = Web.Contents(token_uri, [
            Content = Text.ToBinary(Uri.BuildQueryString(queryWithCode)),
            Headers = [
                #"Content-type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                #"Accept" = "application/json"
            ],
            ManualStatusHandling = {400} 
        ]),
        body = Json.Document(tokenResponse),
        result = if (Record.HasFields(body, {"error", "error_description"})) then 
                    error Error.Record(body[error], body[error_description], body)
                 else
                    body
    in
        result;

Value.IfNull = (a, b) => if a <> null then a else b;

GetScopeString = (scopes as list, optional scopePrefix as text) as text =>
    let
        prefix = Value.IfNull(scopePrefix, ""),
        addPrefix = List.Transform(scopes, each prefix & _),
        asText = Text.Combine(addPrefix, " ")
    in
        asText;
        

JaimesXeroConnector.Icons = [
    Icon16 = { Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector16.png"), Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector20.png"), Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector24.png"), Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector32.png") },
    Icon32 = { Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector32.png"), Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector40.png"), Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector48.png"), Extension.Contents("JaimesXeroConnector64.png") }
];
```

Comment: Are you using data gateway?

Comment: No, because Xero API is a cloud data source. I believe data gateway is for on-premises data sources?

Comment: [Aziz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16549606) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68567649) saying "Have you tried using the codes provided in Xero Developer?"